Swift Regex: How to describe NOT in the builder?
Imagine this expression /[^0-9]/. Match any character that is NOT a digit (a number between 0 and 9).
private let pattern = Regex {
    Capture { /[^0-9]/ }
}

But how is this written using RegexBuilder components? I am missing a NOT component.
// WRONG
private let pattern = Regex {
    Capture { Not(.digit) }
}

// WRONG
private let pattern = Regex {
    Capture { 
        !CharacterClass(.digit)
    }
}


import RegexBuilder

private let pattern = Regex {
    ("0"..."9")
        .inverted
}

You always can try convert regex to regex-builder from refactor menu:


I was not aware of that functionality. You sir, are a legend. Have a wonderful day.
